# How can you create multiple cursors in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

What are the keyboard shortcuts for creating multiple cursors in VS Code?

Comment: Just hold down the `Alt` button and start clicking in different places. That's it.

Comment: CMD+Alt+Down arrow is what you want. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037808/multiline-editing-in-vscode

Comment: If you're using a mac, SHIFT+CTRL+DOWN/UP is what you actually want as of 1.14.2.

Comment: Also, it looks like Cmd+Alt+Down is mapped by editor.action.goToDeclaration by default as of 1.14.2

Comment: As of now, we can use middle mouse button to select multiple columns. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_column-selection-using-middle-mouse-button

Comment: If you're on Mint, you can just disable the Alt Click going to System Settings, Window, Behavior and then changing the "Special key to move and resize window".

Comment: On MacOS, you currently do it by holding down CMD while clicking.

Comment: What about Linux ? Ctrl + click, Alt + click, Shift + click none is working. Thanks.

Comment: Linux (tested on Ubuntu) `Ctrl`+`Shift` `⬆` or `⬇` does multi select
 - Also `alt` + `click`

Comment: `editor.action.selectHighlights` is most likely what you need. Cmd+Shift+p (Ctr+Shift+p) > type `keyboard shortcuts`, paste `editor.action.selectHighlights` and double-click to assign your own shortcut.

Comment: On Mac it is `Option` button so Just hold down the `⌥` aka `option` button and start clicking in different places. That's it. :)

Comment: MacOS:  The _keyboard_ shortcut is Shift + Alt/Option + Command + 'arrow key'.

Comment: Yay, thanks, <kbd>Shift + Option + Command + arrows</kbd> worked!

Answer (score 853):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click. This works on Windows and Linux*, and it should work on Mac, too.

More multi-cursor features are now available in Visual Studio Code 0.2:

> Multi cursor improvements
>   <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd+D</kbd> on Mac) selects next occurrence of word under cursor or of the current selection
>   <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> moves last added cursor to next occurrence of word under cursor or of the current selection
>   The commands use matchCase by default. If the find widget is open, then the find widget settings (matchCase / matchWholeWord) will be used for determining the next occurrence
>   <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd+U</kbd> on Mac) undoes the last cursor action, so if you added a cursor too many or made a mistake, you can press <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd+U</kbd> on Mac) to go back to the previous cursor state.
>   Adding cursor up or down (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Up</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Down</kbd>) (<kbd>Cmd+Alt+Up</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd+Alt+Down</kbd> on Mac) now reveals the last added cursor to make it easier to work with multiple cursors on more than 1 viewport height at a time (i.e. select 300 lines and only 80 fit in the viewport).
>
> ### This makes it a lot easier to introduce multiple cursors

* Linux drag-window conflict:

> Some distros (e.g. Ubuntu) assign window dragging to <kbd>Alt+LeftMouse</kbd>, which will conflict with VSCode.
>
> So, recent versions of VSCode let you toggle between <kbd>Alt+LeftMouse</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+LeftMouse</kbd> under the Selection menu, as detailed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453729).
>
> Alternately, you could change your OS key bindings using `gsettings` as mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30029783/1026023).

Comment: F2 or Ctrl+F2 may help. But haven't found something like Ctrl+D.

Comment: I'm using version 0.5.0. It still doesn't work if the selection has punctuation in it. I cannot select all occurrences of 'http://' with Ctrl+F2 but Ctrl+D works ok... Problem reported [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/issues/detail/18227).

Comment: In the VS Code Intro Videos, there is [a video](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/codeediting) that gives this tip: put the cursor where you want it, hold down the option/alt key, then click anywhere else for an additional cursor. Simple. Works with `OSX 10.10.5`/`VS Code 1.8.1`.

Comment: Alt+click doesn't seem to work on Linux. What did work for me was Ctrl+shift+left/right/up/down

Comment: alt + shift + click on mac (2017)

Comment: alt + shift + click works on Linux (Ubuntu), too.

Comment: (July 2017) Ctrl+D now works. It adds a cursor to the next text match you are currently editing (i.e same effect as sublime)

Comment: alt + shift + click not working on Linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: hmmm, ctrl+alt+up or down rotates my screen (on win10) instead of multiple cursor

Comment: @Reinsbrain try disable that hot key provided by your GPU driver, maybe right click on desktop and checkout related menu items.

Comment: @vilicvane : found disable hot key option under systray icon for intel graphics - thanks :)

Comment: This is great, I would just add the following: alt + shift + I turns a multi-line selection in multiple cursors

Comment: Why are there references to 'alt' on Mac?  There is no 'alt' key on Mac.  There is 'control', 'option', and 'command'.

For Mac users, here is an answer which works:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037808/multiline-editing-in-vscode

Comment: For mac in 2019 with jetbrains keyboard settings, Cmd+click works for me. This doesn't make any sense, because https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_multi-cursor-selection says it should be alt click, and that's what it is in jetbrains, but cmd+click what's working for me in Feb 2019.

Comment: If you're on Mint, you can just disable the Alt Click going to System Settings, Window, Behavior and then changing the "Special key to move and resize window".

Comment: The comment from Hoff (May 13 '17 at 11:53) was the only one in this humongous Answer pile that works for me: ALT + SHIFT will let you freely select any code across multiple lines at any position.

Comment: `Press Alt and click. This works on Windows and Linux*, and it should work on Mac, too.` 
For mac is `⌘` + click on next line(s) as `Alt` doesn't exist.

Comment: Jetbrains products have a shortcut where if I double tap and then hold ctrl, I can then use up and down arrows to add multiple cursors above and below. Seems to not be in vscode, i'm wondering if there's a way to do something similar (it's very hard to live without).

Comment: This now seems to be `ctrl`+ click instead of `alt`+ click (on my Windows machine at least).

Comment: Thanks @vilicvane. `Alt`+ click is not working in my VSCode. I am using Linux Mint 21.3 and VSCode is like below. 
Version: 1.86.2
Commit: 903b1e9d8990623e3d7da1df3d33db3e42d80eda
Date: 2024-02-13T19:41:37.860Z
Electron: 27.2.3
ElectronBuildId: 26908389
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.1.0-1034-oem

Answer (score 275):

## Multi-word (and multi-line) cursors/selection in VS Code

### Multi-word:

Windows / OS X:

- <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+L</kbd> / <kbd>⌘+Shift+L</kbd> selects all instances of the current highlighted word
- <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> / <kbd>⌘+D</kbd> selects the next instance... and the one after that... etc.

### Multi-line:

For *multi-line* selection, <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Down</kbd> / <kbd>⌘+Alt+Shift+Down</kbd> will extend your selection or cursor position to the next line. <kbd>Ctrl+Right</kbd> / <kbd>⌘+Right</kbd> will move to the end of each line, no matter how long. To escape the multi-line selection, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

See the [VS Code keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings) (OS sensitive)

Comment: Ha ha on my machine the Intel video driver has a hot-key Ctrl-Alt-Down to make the screen go upside down. Caught me off guard :)_

Comment: Why is not the same as SSMS (and presumably Visual Studio), which uses Shift-Alt-Down/Up, not Ctrl-Alt-Down???

Comment: @DaveBoltman - I don't know! But you can customise the keybindings.

Comment: To disable the dumb Intel hotkey, you can just right click on desktop > Graphic options > Hotkeys > Disable

Comment: ⌘+Shift+L works on my mac, but for some reason Ctrl+Shift+L doesn't work on my pc :(:(

Comment: EDIT: It was Ctrl+F2 instead

Answer (score 189):

*May 2017*
As of version 1.13 
Add multiple cursors with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + **`Click`**

**`VSCode`** developers have introduced a new setting, `editor.multiCursorModifier`, to change the modifier key for applying multiple cursors to <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + **`Click`** on macOS and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **`Click`** on Windows and Linux. This lets users coming from other editors such as Sublime Text or Atom continue to use the keyboard modifier they are familiar with.

The setting can be set to:

- `ctrl/Cmd` - Maps to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on macOS.
- `alt` - The existing default <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

There's also a new menu item Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **`Click`** for **`Multi-Cursor`** in the **`Selection`** menu to quickly toggle this setting.
[image]

The **Go To Definition** and **Open Link** gestures will also respect this setting and adapt such that they do not conflict. For example, when the setting is `ctrl/Cmd`, multiple cursors can be added with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + **`Click`**, and opening links or going to definition can be invoked with <kbd>Alt</kbd> +**`Click`**.

With fixing Issue #2106, it is now possible to also remove a cursor by using the same gesture on top of an existing selection.

Comment: I was going nuts on why Ctrl+click wasn't working. Didn't know there was an option to toggle it. :-)

Comment: Setting the `editor.multiCursorModifier` from *alt* to  *ctrlCmd* worked great.  Now all I have to do is *ctrl + click* and it will use multiple cursors :)  Muchas gracias!

Comment: I can change to Ctrl + click, it works, but to go to definition of class or something is gone, how can I fix?

Comment: This is the most helpful answer. In most editors CTRL+click is used for multiple selection. There is no need to modify the OS behaviour to make an editor work. This option modifies the behaviour for multiple selection to the most commonly used pattern.

Answer (score 145):

I had problem with ALT key, fix is to change `alt+click` as a Gnome hotkey which clobbers multi-cursor select in VSCode, to `super+click` by running:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier "<Super>"
```

Source: http://2buntu.com/articles/1529/visual-studio-code-comes-to-linux/

Comment: +1 this method works! Just verified it with Ubuntu 14.04.05.. Earlier I tried `dconf-editor` and `CompizConfig` to change "move window" plugin configurations and messed up and almost broke my Ubuntu.

Comment: This works in Ubuntu!

Comment: Use `gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier "<Super>"` for Linux Mint (Cinnamon).

Comment: Awesome! Works on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: If you do not want to touch your system default settings, you may also use "Selection > Switch to CTRL+Click for Multi-Cursor". This works in Linux Mint, so it should work in Ubuntu too.

Comment: If you want to change the system setting in Linux Mint Cinnamon, you may also go to "System Settings > Preferences > Windows > Behavior" and change the "Special key to move and resize windows".

Comment: What if I don't want to change the system-wide shortcut (which I'm already used to)? The option "Selection > Switch to CTRL+Click for Multi-Cursor" does not really work, as it then automatically rebinds the "Go to definition" command from CTRL+Click to ALT+Click, which again conflicts with the system shortcut for dragging windows.

Comment: In KDE Plasma change "Alt+Left click" setting from "Move" to "Do nothing" in "System Settings"->"Window Management"->"Window Behavior"->"Window Actions"

Answer (score 112):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⬇ / ⬆</kbd>, without mouse, or hold "alt" and click on all the lines you want.

**Note**: Tested on Windows.

Comment: `CMD`+`OPTION`+`SHIFT`+`⬇ / ⬆` works for me on Mac with version 1.15.1.

Comment: On windows 10 I'm able to do it without the `shift`

Comment: You can also use page up/down to go faster!

Comment: without `SHIFT` it wasn't working for me thx

Comment: I installed [Smart Multi-cursor](https://github.com/idanpa/vscode-smartmulticursor) extension with some advanced features, with shortcut Cmd + Alt + (Up / Down) to create the multi-cursor.

Answer (score 62):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>⬇ / ⬆</kbd> works for me on newest VSCode 1.29.1 and newest OSX High Sierra 10.13.6, Macbook Pro.

This adds a vertical line up/down on screen, like <kbd>Option</kbd>+Click/Vertical Drag does in Sublime Text.

To add multiple cursors **at any points in your file**, including multiple ones on **the same line**, do <kbd>Cmd (or Option)</kbd>+Click anywhere you want, shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-w8laWcnes). You may also search for text (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+F) that repeats multiple times, then press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> to add cursors at end of EACH word.

Answer (score 35):

As of Visual Studio Code version 0.10.9, you can now do a **Create Multiple Cursors from Selected Lines** by selecting multiple lines, and pressing <kbd>Shift+Alt+I</kbd>

Note: This is similar to Sublime Text's <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+L</kbd> functionality.

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/vJanuary#_thank-you
Relevant PR: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/1479

Comment: `Shift+Alt+<arrow>` worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! `Shift+Alt+I` works like a charm!

Answer (score 34):

On XFCE, go to `Applications -> Settings -> Settings editor - > xfwm4 -> easy_click(disable value)`

Now you can `Insert Cursor` with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Click

I've also disabled L/R Workspace (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>L/R</kbd>) settings in `Settings -> Window manager -> Keyboard`

Comment: ?? what is XFCE here?

Comment: @Martian2049, it's a Desktop Environment on Unix-like operating systems (Linux, BSD etc). If you don't know this yet, probably my answer won't be useful for you, go check other answers.

Comment: It's working after disabling easy_click for me, thanks you saved my day.

Comment: It's working for me. I changed in easy_click ALT to CTRL because ALT + click is for moving windows.

Comment: Nice reply. It works for me @lava-lava.

Comment: This works in 2023! You saved me so much trouble, thanks mate!

Answer (score 31):

On **Ubuntu**, in order to enable multi-cursor clicking you will need to re-assign Alt+click first, by running the command below. This is because by default Ubuntu uses the shortcut itself and has it takes precedence.

```
> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier "<Super>"
```

Answer (score 19):

There is no binding for exactly what you want.

The only thing that comes close is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> which will select all of them at once.

You can bind it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> doing the following:

- Click on `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`
  You should see a pane full of the current bindings and on the right a list of custom bindings
- In the current bindings, search for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and copy that whole line and paste it into the right pane.
- You might have to remove the comma at the end and then change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and then save the file.

It should look something like this:

```json
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+d",
    "command": "editor.action.changeAll",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can i make it multicursor like, sublime does .. pressing the mousewheel?

Comment: @MigueI haven't found a way to do that yet

Comment: When you don't want to search and replace, this is the most efficient way if you have thousands of rows to edit at the same time ! THX !

Answer (score 18):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⬇ / ⬆</kbd> add cursors above and below the current line.  Still nowhere near as good as sublime or brackets though. I can't see anything equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in sublime in the keyboard shortcuts file.

Comment: For Mac it is: `Alt + Command` and up or down arrow.

Comment: On Ubuntu this is `Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down`

Comment: In Windows that seems to default to "rotate screen".

Comment: If it's rotating your screen, that's your graphics driver, not windows. You can disable that shortcut from the graphics settings.

Comment: Works for me! :)

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, IMO. Would be even more helpful if it contains the hotkey setting name "Add Cursor Below/Above", however VS codes allow searching by the key combination so it's not a biggie.

Answer (score 9):

https://code.visualstudio.com/Updates

New version (Visual Studio 0.3.0) support more multi cursor feature.

```
Multi-cursor
Here's multi-cursor improvements that we've made.

⌘D selects the word at the cursor, or the next occurrence of the current selection.
⌘K ⌘D moves the last added cursor to next occurrence of the current selection.
The two actions pick up the matchCase and matchWholeWord settings of the find widget.
⌘U undoes the last cursor action, so if you added one cursor too many or made a mistake, press ⌘U to return to the previous cursor state.
Insert cursor above (⌥⌘↑) and insert cursor below (⌥⌘↓) now reveals the last added cursor, making it easier to work with multi-cursors spanning more than one screen height (i.e., working with 300 lines while only 80 fit in the screen).
```

And short cut of select multi cursor change into cmd + d(it's same as Sublime Text. lol)

We can expect that next version supports more convenient feature about multi cursor ;)

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click. It works in Windows.

Details: [Visual Studio Code Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_selection-multicursor)

Comment: Thanks, Same works for mac

Answer (score 7):

In Visual Studio without mouse: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>{ Arrow }</kbd>.

Comment: `Alt+Shift+{ Arrow }`. will result in copying of the current line as of VS Code V1.18.0

Answer (score 7):

In my XFCE (version 4.12), it's in `Settings -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Accessibility`.

There's a dropdown field `Key used to grab and move windows:`, set this to `None`.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + Click works now in VS Code to add more cursor.

Comment: For Linux mint 20 Go to menu->type window->click on `windows`->choose `behaviour` tab and go down to `moving and resizing windows` Change `special key to move and resize windows` to something different from Alt

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following per the Selection menu:

[image: Screenshot of Selection menu in VS Code]

Press/hold <kbd>Alt+Ctrl+Up Arrow</kbd>/<kbd>Alt+Ctrl+Down Arrow</kbd>  as required to create sufficient cursors, then <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> can be used to expand the selections.

Answer (score 5):

For xfce users, just go to `settings>window manager tweaks>accessibility` there change the `key used to grab and move windows:` to `super` as demonstrated in the image below.[image]

Now you can use <kbd>super</kbd> instead of alt. Wallah!! Go make multiple cursors by <kbd>alt + click</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue on Ubuntu-MATE, but here you resolve it by:

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.general mouse-button-modifier "<Super>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Alt + Command + Shift will add a cursor to the next instance of what you've selected. E.g. a variable or function name

Answer (score 0):

First go to "Keyboard Shortcuts", you can get there by hitting <kbd>Cmd+k</kbd> then <kbd>Cmd+s</kbd>, or for Windows <kbd>Ctrl+k</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl+s</kbd>.

Once you're there, search for "Add Cursor Above" and "Add Cursor Below". You can even assign them your own key-bindings.

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple cursor on selected word** 
*Use case* - if you have a large document and want to modify some word or select a line containing that word.

I'll walk through with one example 
Suppose you have a document (of any type) like

```
{
    x: xval1,
    y: yval1,
    z: zval1
},
{
    x: xval2,
    y: yval2,
    z: zval2
},
{
    x: xval3,
    y: yval3,
    z: zval3
}
```

You want to select all the values associated with x and expecting output like this \

```
x: xval1,
x: xval2,
x: xval3,
```

Steps to achieve this output using vscode only -

1. find (<kbd>command + f</kbd>) with "x:"
2. (<kbd>**option + enter**</kbd>) for multiple cursors on each occurrence of "x:".
3. Move all cursors to the left of the lines using (<kbd>command + left arrow</kbd>)
4. Now, select the whole line by (<kbd>command + shift + right arrow</kbd>)
5. Copy (<kbd>command + c</kbd>) the content
6. Paste (<kbd>command + v</kbd>) it anywhere you want

I want to emphasise on the second step how much strong this command can be.

Answer (score -2):

On windows:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> if you are using vscode
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> if you are using visual studio

Answer (score -3):

Alt + Click works in OSX. Code Version 1.14.2

Answer (score -3):

### For Ubuntu Users

`ALT` + `SHIFT` + `⬇ / ⬆`

Comment: Copies the line above/below