# Multiline editing in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to enable multiline editing like in [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text)?

For example, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to place additional cursor carets and being able to write/delete on multiple places in the document at one time.

Comment: In many mac apps (e.g. TextEdit) I can also Option-drag the mouse to select a box. Is this available in VS Code?

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29953479/465053).

Comment: From April 2018 (version 1.23), we can use middle mouse button to select multiple columns. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_column-selection-using-middle-mouse-button

Comment: For anyone looking for the name of this command in the keyboard shortcuts section, it's: `editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected`

Comment: @enzoborgfrantz +1 Exactly what I was looking for! The selected answer should have first mentioned the relevant editor commands because the keybindings can vary.

Comment: Meanwhile here is a **Keyboard Shortcut Reference** for VS Code in Windows - https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Comment: Mac: `OPTION + SHIFT + I` adds a cursor to the end of every line in the selected/highlighted text. Much faster than adding an individual cursor to every line if you have a lot of lines

Answer (score 1783, accepted):

On Windows, you hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> while pressing the up <kbd>↑</kbd> or down <kbd>↓</kbd> arrow keys to add cursors.

Mac: <kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>

Linux: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>

> Note that third-party software may interfere with these shortcuts, preventing them from working as intended (particularly Intel's HD Graphics software on Windows; see comments for more details).
>
> If you experience this issue, you can either disable the Intel/other software hotkeys, or modify the VS Code shortcuts (described below).

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to reset to a single cursor.

[image: Multiline cursors in Visual Studio Code]

Or, [as Isidor Nikolic points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30047339), you can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and left click to place cursors arbitrarily.

[image: Arbitrarily placed multiline cursors in Visual Studio Code]

You can view and edit keyboard shortcuts via:

> File → Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts

Documentation:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings

Official VS Code Keyboard shortcut cheat sheets:

https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf
https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf
https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf

Comment: On windows, the first option just flips my screen. :-/

Comment: I've seen videos of folks using this to search for items and edit. How would you search for some text that appears in several places and multiline edit to another value. I've tried using Ctrl+Alt and Ctrl-Alt-F3, but to no avail.

Comment: @KristofferlaCour Try using the alt on the other side of the keyboard, I was having the same flip issue when i used ctrl + alt together on the left side, but left ctrl and right alt along with left shift and up/down works.

Comment: This is not valid any more. Try `CTRL + SHIFT + UP/DOWN/CLICK` OR `ALT + SHIFT + UP/DOWN/CLICK`

Comment: @Han what do you mean it "is not valid any more"; the shortcuts mentioned in the answer are still the same in the latest version of VSCode and you can see them listed in the official shortcut cheat-sheet for windows located here: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Comment: Don't know why. Mine is Linux version. I never change the  keyboard setting.

Comment: @Nacimota - on a windows 10 machine (just tested now) the combination CTRL+ALT+ARROW will flip the screen, CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+ARROW will create a new cursor. The published list of keyboard shortcuts PDF may be out of date.

Comment: @AlexC the shortcuts are ***not*** out of date; download the latest build and look at the configuration yourself. If you're finding that the shortcuts  listed are flipping your screen, I'd wager it's because you have an Intel GPU and are running the Intel software for it which intercepts these shortcuts by default. Open the HD Graphics software and disable or rebind hotkeys if it bothers you, but _do not edit my post to add incorrect information_. The shortcuts listed are accurate, and I am not going to list every piece of 3rd party software that may or may not interfere with them.

Comment: @Nacimota with all due respect, it was an honest mistake which represents reality for a significant portion of users. There are enough intel machines out there where this might be a default configuration that the additional information was valuable. We both have the goal of providing the best most up to date answer. An additional sentence to enumerate that difference would be helpful.

Comment: @AlexC had same issue, it was the hotkeys for the Intel card causing the problem.

Comment: This is so weird, that they decided to use some random shortcuts for column mode. It's been years as it works the same in many editors. Visual Studio or even Notepad++ work the same and it's always been Alt+Shift+Up/Down/Left/Right. In VSCode you cannot even do left/right to make a selection

Comment: I had the same screen flipping issue, but I don't think @Nacimota needs to modify the answer. However, to prevent people like me from having to stand on their heads until we find out how to correct the flip, can you please add to the answer that "some 3rd party software may interfere with these shortcuts, see comments"? Again, you don't have to do this, but lot of people will be thankful if you do. Have a +1 for your great answer.

Comment: On Windows 10 I use ALT + mouse click  ==> to create a new insert cursor

Comment: I don't see a way to perform a multi line delete of all selected elements on mac, did i missed something?

Comment: This has just blown my mind once I edited multiple lines at once!  BTW CTRL + ALT + up/down arrows works on Win10. Verified today. Thanks!

Comment: doing `CTRL` + `SHIFT` and an arrow key flips the screen on windows pc's, using `ALT` and left clicking where you want the other cursors does the trick

Comment: @mast3rd3mon if you read the answer and previous comments you will learn that the screen flipping is due to third party software, not Windows.

Comment: @Nacimota the claim was that it was probably the intel graphics yet it also does it on amd gpu's and nvidea gpu's. I'm more inclined to say its a feature of windows as i have never known a windows machine _not_ flip the screen

Comment: @mast3rd3mon well allow me to disprove your statement with a counterexample. I have systems with both AMD and Nvidia GPUs and this shortcut definitely does *not* flip the screen on any of them. Even if it did, I still assert that it would be third party software doing it even if it isn't Intel HD Graphics *specifically*; I simply pointed to the Intel software because it is by far the most common common cause, but not necessarily a unique one. I challenge you - or anyone else - to actually **prove** that this is a Windows feature, rather than just assuming it to be true.

Comment: My AMD cpu with nvidea graphics flipped the screen, my AMD cpu with AMD graphics flips the screen, another pc in my house with an intel cpu and AMD graphics also flips the screen. None use intel graphics and only 1 of the 3 pc configs use intel cpu's but all run Windows

Comment: @mast3rd3mon, the fact that all those machines run Windows doesn't prove anything except... that they all run Windows. I've already given you examples that *don't* behave that way, so it's really bizarre to me that you still *insist* on saying that it's a Windows shortcut, with no **conclusive** evidence. How do you explain all the people with Windows machines whose screens do not flip, including the developers *from Microsoft* who chose the shortcut in the first place? Can you find the shortcut on this page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts ?

Comment: @Nacimota well i am still yet to come across a windows pc that cant flip the screen. So either every machine ive ever used has this "third party software" as you say, or its an underlying feature in windows

Comment: @mast3rd3mon this conversation is going in circles now. If you have any proof *beyond your own personal anecdotes* that it's a Windows shortcut, I'd be happy to admit I'm wrong. In any case, it doesn't really matter because the shortcut is correct for VSCode on Windows which you can verify in both the documentation and default configuration files. There's also a notice about the shortcuts conflicting with other software for some people (whether it's Windows or something else), so there is really nothing in the answer that needs to be modified.

Comment: On Windows (instead of filliping your monitor):
 1) upper left corner of desired selection: leftclick
 2) lower right corner of desired selection: shift+alt+leftclick

See the other answer on this question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41703355/3100771)

Comment: The answer should IMO present the alternative solution ctrl-alt-shift + arrows since it is a very common issue as evident from the comments.


Another solution is simply to open the Intel Graphics control panel -> settings -> disable keyboard shortcuts. This also "proves" that Nacimota is right in that this is a Intel issue, not a windows issue.


However as I said, I strongly support adding a line with the solution for Intel folks. @Nacimota would you be in favor of such a solution? Splitting the windows solution in two?  Maybe also explain that the intel shortcuts can be removed?

Comment: @AlexTelon I don't agree that the answer should display `ctrl`+`alt`+`shift` because that's not what the shortcut is and it's not a sensible workaround. The appropriate solution is to either A) disable the hotkeys in the Intel/other software if you don't use them; or B) rebind the shortcut to another sequence in vscode. I may update the answer to make this a little clearer but I'm not writing anything that someone might accidentally read as *"`ctrl`+`alt`+`shift` is the shortcut"* because that is evidently not the case, and it's not a problem that affects all (or even most, afaik) users.

Comment: @Nacimota I approve of your edit. The addition of shift would only "solve" the issue in the short-term. The real solution should be to disable the intel shortcuts if one never uses them anyways or change shortcuts in visual studio.

Comment: Can you do something like that in VS Community? Multi cursors keeping pressed `Alt` etc.?

Comment: On Mac, the most useful option for me is to select the first occurrence of what I want to change, then hit ⌘ Cmd + D to add cursors to the matches below.  All of the shortcuts are provided in the Selection Menu.

Comment: You can disable the screen rotation on Windows 7 with a right click on the desktop. Select Graphics Options -> Hotkeys -> Disable

Comment: ctl-alt- up arrow flips my screen

Comment: @Loveandpeace-JoeCodeswell I'm assuming that's why you downvoted, even though your issue is addressed in both the answer and the comments?

Comment: `ctrl`+ `shift`+`alt` + `arrow keys up or down` now does the trick

Comment: @EbrahimKaram unless you have an official source that the default keybindings have changed, I direct you back to the answer and comments that have already addressed this.

Comment: click + dragging with middle mouse button also works

Comment: This solution won't work if matching words are at different positions over multiple lines, instead @user8202629 solution works in all scenarios

Answer (score 255):

Solved using just two steps!

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

It's equal to Sublime Text's <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.

---

<sup>Note: For macOS, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> followed by <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> is equivalent to Sublime Text's <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.</sup>

[image]

Comment: The same effect gives you hitting ctrl+F2

Comment: Can we select all lines at a time containing that keyword ?
Sublime text had it Ctrl + F > Alt + F3 > Ctrl + L

Comment: What is this in Mac terms? Ctrl and Alt replaced by...?

Comment: This is easy and should have been accepted answer

Comment: Nice! Thank you. It was not covered in the starter docs.

Comment: @ksopyla and `Ctrl-Shift-L` on Linux.

Comment: Thank you so much! `Alt + Enter` and `Ctrl + Shift + L` are equivalent.

Answer (score 118):

You can just <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click for additional cursors. And as already mentioned, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> or   <kbd>↓</kbd>.

Comment: And you can use Alt+Shift+click to select two lines and every line in between.

Comment: Question is, how to edit its Key Binding (What is `Alt + Click` 's name?)

Comment: Alt + click automatically defines the word, or moves to the left of the word and does not work for me.

Comment: Found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44450888/1454514) to my question, it can either be **Alt** (which is _default_, or **Ctrl / ⌘**. 
   This option can be modified with the `"editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd"` key in `settings.json`.

Comment: If you open the UI settings and search for "multi cursor" the options for this should pop right up

Answer (score 97):

Box Selecting

Windows: <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Left Button</kbd>

macOS: <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>

This is contrary to what is mentioned in [an answer to *Does Visual Studio Code have box select/multi-line edit?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384442/does-visual-studio-code-have-box-select-multi-line-edit/36650448#36650448).

Comment: I'm not a fan of Shift+Alt+Click (although it works). So to make it work (on Windows) just like in VS, I did this: go to Selection menu, and select Switch to Alt+Click for Multi-Cursor. Now Alt+Click does box selecting.

Answer (score 75):

I wanted to select multiple lines and hit "something" to have a cursor for each select lines (similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in Sublime Text). This action in Visual Studio Code is called "Add Cursors to Line Ends".

This was tested in Visual Studio Code 1.77.0 (April 2023) and works on both **Windows** and **Mac**.

Here is the way:

1. Select the lines you want to have multiple cursors.
2. Simply hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>.

You now have one cursor per selected line.

Comment: @Manza In VS Code, you it's `ALT-SHIFT-I` (like `i` not `L`). The font doesn't help to see correctly. I use this command multiple times per day on both Mac and Windows and just tested once again with the latest version of VS Code : 1.24.1 and I assure you it works. Maybe you have a plugin causing conflict ?

Comment: wow yeah, that do the trick, thank you so much, i was still flipping between sublime becuase of this feature, is the soooo handy

Comment: for me it's CTRL-SHIFT-L (windows)

Comment: This is what I was looking for, you can modify it in vs studio settings looking for the "add cursors to line ends" keybindings.

Answer (score 47):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to use multi word edit of same words in Windows and Linux.

Use <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> for Mac.

Comment: As @Krishnaraj said, Ctrl + D work. Actually both VSCode and Sublime support this. Make sure apply Ctrl + D on all later occurrence without releasing ctrl. Yeah, you still need manually select, it just help you free your mouse.
MacOS Command + D

Comment: And note: Ctrl + D only works for 'Next selection', 'Previous selection' is only accessible via Ctrl + P and then typying: '>Add Selection To Previous Find Match' (of a part of that text!)

Answer (score 34):

In the latest release of Visual Studio Code, you can now drag the cursor while holding <kbd>Option</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd> on Windows) to select the same column on multiple rows.

To enable this, make sure you change your `editor.multiCursorModifier` to look like this:

```
"editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd"
```

From the Visual Studio Code release notes 1.32.0:

> In the following video, the selection begins as a regular selection and then Alt is pressed and held until the mouse button is released:

[image: Example of improved column selection:]

Comment: Thank you, this works. It's funny though how "alt" does not work, by contrast "ctrlCmd" actually makes it work with the ALT-key. *head explodes*

Comment: @tyler-becks how did you make this GIF?

Comment: @bvdb I think what's happening is that having Alt as the multi cursor modifier is preventing it working with a drag to do a box select

Comment: how to open settings JSON in VSC to complete the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file#answer-65909052

Answer (score 29):

From the [version 1.13 (May 2017)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_13#_add-multiple-cursors-with-ctrl-cmd-click) you can finally change the default modifier key for creating multiple cursors (add to settings):

```
"editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd"
```

P.S.: The modifier "follow link" from this moment will be <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: A lot of these other answers are not addressing the question. This one is - how to place extra carets with mouse clicks.

Answer (score 24):

**Step 1:** 
 
Select the word to be replaced.

---

**Step 2:**

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to select its multiple occurrences.

---

**Step 3:** 
 
Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to set cursor at all the found occurrences.

---

**Step 4:** 
Just start typing the new word.

---

**Alternatively on Mac:** 
<kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> to set cursor on the click location.

Comment: Also `cmd+shift+L` on Mac. Does the same thing in one step.

Comment: @Andres Thanks! This did solve my issue at Windows, the other solutions flip my screen.

Answer (score 22):

On Mac it is:

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> while pressing the up <kbd>↑</kbd> or down <kbd>↓</kbd> arrow keys.

Answer (score 20):

I am using the [vscodevim](https://github.com/VSCodeVim) extension, so I'm not sure if this is a common problem. But, I was having the issue where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>UpArrow</kbd> flipped my screen upside down.

Looking at the [Visual Studio Code Basics](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics) (I don't know if they changed this in a recent update), it says to use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + (<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd>)

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + [Arrow Key] is a common keyboard shortcut for screen rotation, certainly with Intel graphics drivers and / or associated software. I imagine it is being intercepted by this before VSCode gets a look in. Recently (and annoyingly, since I used to use it) rotation seems to have been discontinued in an update to the Intel software and is now only available through long-winded menus in Windows. The keyboard shortcut should therefore work in VSCode with more recent drivers.

Answer (score 16):

Working solution for me was *first selecting the required text* to edit and then using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to select all matching data in the page.
You may also use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> as suggested by [@lesterCovax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59754392/7446645)

> **Please Note:** The above solution uses the inherent ability of VSCode editor to select similar text across the entire page, and therefore, be careful.

For me the above solution of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Arrowkeys</kbd> did not work as it caused the screen to change its display orientation against selecting the lines in VSCode.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

**(Windows 10 pro x64) Here have some ways!**

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd>
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd>
3. Keybindings: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `click` (??? it doesn't work!)

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites?newreg=f91a052d54e149c28ae5de0372a58ab4

Answer (score 13):

- To add multiple cursors at any text position
  This is done by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>. Firstly you have to enable **Multiple-Cursor Modifier**. Simply type this option on **Command Palette** by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to enable it.
- To remove a cursor form multiple text position.
  Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on the cursor.

Answer (score 12):

## [version 1.43 (February 2020)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_43#_column-selection-mode)

You can now toggle column selection mode, which changes mouse gestures and arrow keys, via:

- Menu Bar > Selection > Column Selection Mode
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Show All Commands) > Toggle Column Selection Mode
- Bind your key for command `"editor.action.toggleColumnSelection"`

[image]

Note: There is a "Column Selection" panel in the status bar after activation, which you can press to disable it again.

Answer (score 10):

[As of April 2018 (version 1.23)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_column-selection-using-middle-mouse-button) you can now also use the middle mouse button to multiline select / box select.

Comment: Thanks for that, it is a time save are there an option for key board? like highlight and then ctrl + l in sublime?

Comment: That's a slightly different feature, but you're probably looking for ctrl+ i. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Answer (score 8):

In addition to all of the answers, there is one more way. Select the lines you want and then press:

- Windows: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

This puts a cursor in every row in the selection.

Comment: How to make the same, but place the cursors in the beginning of the lines?

Answer (score 8):

According to VS Code 1.55.2 version(2021) under **User > Commonly** Used section there is an option as `Multi Cursor Modifier`. See below image.
[image]

for *multi cursor* default key is `alt` if you want it can change to `Ctrl`.
Moreover, for suitable places, you can **hold** the `Middle Mouse button` and **move to down**.

Answer (score 7):

In Windows, the below combinations work for me:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>down arrow</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>up arrow</kbd>

Comment: This appears to be identical to Visual Studio!

Answer (score 5):

I think it depends on your Visual Studio Code version.

Mine is Linux version Visual Studio Code 1.7.2.

```json
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+up",         "command": "editor.action.insertCursorAbove",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "shift+alt+up",          "command": "editor.action.insertCursorAbove",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+down",       "command": "editor.action.insertCursorBelow",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "shift+alt+down",        "command": "editor.action.insertCursorBelow",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus" }
```

The point is the shortcuts are not same in all machines, so you should check your configuration. Go to menu:

> Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts*

Search for `editor.action.insertCursorAbove` and `editor.action.insertCursorBelow` and see your current configurations. You may change them if they conflict with operating system's shortcut keys.

Comment: Adding the SHIFT + ALT + UP/DOWN to my user settings worked on Windows 10

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio Code just press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and place your cursor to the edit place(where you want to edit) and right click to select.

Comment: This answer seems incomplete

Answer (score 5):

### (NO MOUSE) For macOS, I found this to be very quick!

1. `CMD` + `f`  To search the (word) you want to change.
2. `Option` + `Enter` To select all word you search for.

Just update the first word and it will update all the selected.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I used the `Alt` key to select the lines where I wanted to edit, and that's it.
Alternatively, we can use the `Ctrl + Alt + UP/DOWN` arrow if the things to be edited are above or below.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Linux, there's a possibility of a conflict with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + *click*, which is the default for "moving a window".

You can go to menu *Settings* → *Window Behavior* → *Window Behavior* → *Actions* tab

Just remove <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> (hold) and it will work.

This is the best way, because you don't need to hold two <kbd>+</kbd> keys to do such a simple task.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the latest version of VS code i.e., 1.46.1 (May 2020) in Windows 10. Just press `Alt`+`mouse left click` on the lines you want to select. This will let you select multiple lines at once and let you edit them. Also Press `Esc` to exit from it.
This is really helpful if you're coming from sublime text.

Answer (score 3):

On **windows**, you can create additional cursor on the next/previous lines by pressing:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>Down</kbd>/<kbd>Up</kbd>

**Missing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> will flip your screen.**

Creating additional cursors will allow you to edit multiple lines at once.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) keymap and the keybinding provided by the top answer did not seem to work :( Could be some conflicts between Visual Studio Code and sublime keymaps.

The keybinding recommended [by @Han](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1776916/han) works for me (much appreciated!):

- Enter multiline cursor mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>
- Exit with <kbd>Esc</kbd>

---

(Sidenote) Below is a small example of using [Emmet](https://emmet.io/) together with the multiline cursor (enabled and disabled with these key bindings listed above):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just <kbd>Opt</kbd> + click works for me on Mac

Answer (score 2):

My settings: Windows 8.1 64 bits, Visual Studio Code version 1.33.1.

Problem: Conflict with keyboard shortcuts of Intel HD Graphics 4000

I had a problem when I was using the default shortcuts of the Visual Studio Code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN</kbd>). In my case, these commands were turning my screen in 0º and 180º respectively. It's happening, because there is the Graphic Intel application installed on my computer. Then, I just disable the shortcuts of this application.

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/373832/disable-alt-arrow-display-flip-keyboard-shortcut/693890) is an tutorial to help someone.

Comment: In Windows 7 you can right click the desktop, select graphics options -> hotkeys -> disable.

Comment: Yes!!! This was the answer for me too, the other suggestions didn't work and the accepted answer flipped my window upside down.

Answer (score 1):

The [solution from @maxime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49901276/10852423) of using `SHIFT + ALT + i` worked for me, when I needed to quickly edit ~20k lines in a file.  Most of the other keyboard shortcuts mentioned are only useful for a limited number of line.  `SHIFT` selecting the area you want to column edit, then pressing `SHIFT + ALT + i` is the most efficient way to handle this.

What I accidentally discovered though, (and hasn't been mentioned here yet) is that ***there is a limit of 10k lines in "cursor edit mode"*** (there's [an open Github feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/81589) to increase it).  This means that for extremely large files, it may be better to script your edits, rather than doing it manually.

For those like [@specimen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037808/multiline-editing-in-visual-studio-code#comment94883831_49901276) that had to use shortcuts like `CTRL + SHIFT + L` (default binding is `Select all occurrences of current selection`) to accomplish this, you should check that you don't have a keymap extension installed.  You can check by searching for `@recommended:keymaps` in the extensions pane, going to `File > Preferences > Keymaps` (`CTRL+K CTRL+M`).

The default [Windows] keymap can be found in PDF form [HERE](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf), or you can go to `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` to find/modify the current bindings.  There is also more in-depth key bindings documentation [HERE](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings).

Answer (score 1):

For me  `Alt` +  `Middle Click` (scroll wheel) worked fine
You have to click on `Alt` then long click on  `Middle Click` then scroll *Up*  or *down*

Answer (score 1):

On Windows..

1. Select **one line** you want to change everywhere. (*with the mouse cursor*)
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and you will start editing **all lines** at once.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer:

1. Install [Multi Line tricks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bigous.vscode-multi-line-tricks) extension for Visual Studio Code
2. Select the lines and press `Alt+Shift+L` (Windows/Linux) or `Option+Shift+L` (Mac)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Fedora (I tried with Fedora 31) with KDE, go to:

> 1. System Settings
> 2. Window Management
> 3. Window Behavior
> 4. Window Actions
> 5. Inner Window, Titlebar and Frame Actions
> 6. Click Left Click Box
> 7. Pick Do nothing (replacing move/drag)

Now you can select multiple lines with **Alt + Left Click**!