# Pressing the end key in multiline mode, makes VSCode leave multiline mode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm able to do [Multiline editing in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037808/multiline-editing-in-vscode) but when I hit the 'end' key, it leaves multiline edit mode.

My lines have different lengths/number of words so <kbd>ctrl+arrow</kbd> doens't work.

Is there a config or other shortcut that would get me to the end of each line without leaving multiline mode?

This [ext](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bigous.vscode-multi-line-tricks) would work, but I'd like to avoid installing any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce. I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click within several lines to add cursors, then I press <kbd>End</kbd>. All cursors move to the ends of the lines.

As an alternative, you can also use the `editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected` command (default keybinding is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) after selecting some lines.