# How to put the cursor at the end of all selected lines in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the following code:

```
CList.Add( new CodeStuff(941,"National List Limit
CList.Add( new CodeStuff(945,"Code not used
CList.Add( new CodeStuff(946,"State Building Height Limit
CList.Add( new CodeStuff(993,"Building Material Type
CList.Add( new CodeStuff(1033,"Not used - requirements changed
CList.Add( new CodeStuff(1034,"Current Unacceptable Applications
CList.Add( new CodeStuff(1035,"Historical Unacceptable Applications
```

I got the first bit using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>mouse button</kbd> and typing. How do I add `");` to the end of each line?

I had to use Notepad++ macro recording to do it and this is the only reason I still hang on to that editor. If someone can tell me how to do it in VSCode, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: You can see the answer in this short YouTube video: https://youtu.be/Fkr2Kbjuefc

Answer (score 14):

Not completely sure I understand, but <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> will put a cursor at the end of all selected lines so just select your text and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> (that is an 'eye' at the end).  Then typing `");` will put that at the end of each line.

----------------------   Edit  -------------------------------

I see that `Column Selection Mode` (in v1.43) does this nicely now (with `Selection/Column Selection Mode` enabled) depending on your direction of selection [unfortunately the gif does a poor job of showing the cursors but they are all at the beginning or ends of the lines depending on the direction of selection]:

[image: column selection cursors]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, had been missing this shortcut for a while now and couldn't find it anywhere!

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10, if I hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>, all the cursors go to the beginning of each line. To move the cursors to the end of each line, simply hit the <kbd>End</kbd> key after that.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac Vscode, I believe the trick is to "mouse" select the lines you wish to append, then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: I keep thinking that's a lowercase L, but it's really a capital i! Thank you!