# Turn multiline selection into multi cursor selection in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

It happens from time to time that I need to edit 100+ lines in a text file all at once.

I know I can use <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> to select multiple lines but depending on the size of the file that takes a while.

In Atom and Sublime, I can just do a <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> to select everything, hit another shortcut (forgot the actual shortcut) and end up with a cursor for every line.

Have not found this in VSCode.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> to select all. (or whatever muli-line selection you want)

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>  will put cursors at end of each selected line.

And then if you want those cursors at the beginning of each line you need to trigger the command "`cursorLineStart`"  which is unbound by default.  Give it a keybinding and all those end-of-line cursors will jump to the beginning of each line.

---

With v1.43 and `Column Selection Mode` this can be quite easy, see [Column selection like Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669867/column-selection-like-visual-studio/60426811#60426811) and [How to put the cursor at the end of all selected lines in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931896/how-to-put-the-cursor-at-the-end-of-all-selected-lines-in-visual-studio-code/49933006#49933006)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW cursorLineStart is not the opposite of Shift-Alt-I. In looking at the commends, Shift-Alt-I is "Add cursors to line ends", but there is not a "Add cursors to line begins" option.

However, the easy trick for that is:

1. Select your text block
2. Shift-Alt-I to put a cursor at the end of each line
3. Command-LeftArrow will move those cursors to the beginning of the lines

Its an extra step but it works. When I get time I will play around with building a custom command to do all this in one action.