# Add multiple cursors to the start of line in VSCode (Windows)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to add multiple cursors at the start of the line in VSCode, just like I can do at the end of the line with `Ctrl + Shift + L` or `Shift + Alt + I`.

I can't find a way to move all multiple cursors at the start of the line either with `Ctrl + Home` as the contents are different on each line.

Here are the contents -

```
ahmadawais.shades-of-purple
akamud.vscode-theme-onedark
AlanWalk.markdown-toc
alefragnani.Bookmarks
alefragnani.project-manager
annsk.alignment
apollographql.vscode-apollo
arcticicestudio.nord-visual-studio-code
be5invis.vscode-icontheme-nomo-dark
bierner.color-info
bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss
burkeholland.simple-react-snippets
ChakrounAnas.turbo-console-log
christian-kohler.npm-intellisense
christian-kohler.path-intellisense
CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer
Dart-Code.dart-code
Dart-Code.flutter
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
donjayamanne.githistory
dracula-theme.theme-dracula
eamodio.gitlens
EditorConfig.EditorConfig
EliverLara.andromeda
Endormi.2077-theme
Equinusocio.vsc-material-theme
esbenp.prettier-vscode
fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight
fabiospampinato.vscode-open-in-github
fabiospampinato.vscode-todo-plus
formulahendry.auto-rename-tag
formulahendry.code-runner
GrapeCity.gc-excelviewer
jakob101.RelativePath
James-Yu.latex-workshop
jasonnutter.search-node-modules
jaspernorth.vscode-pigments
jeroen-meijer.pubspec-assist
jevakallio.vscode-hacker-typer
johnpapa.vscode-peacock
jolaleye.horizon-theme-vscode
jpoissonnier.vscode-styled-components
juanmnl.vscode-theme-1984
Kasik96.swift
kevinkyang.auto-comment-blocks
kumar-harsh.graphql-for-vscode
mathiasfrohlich.Kotlin
MatiasOlivera.universe
max-SS.Cyberpunk
mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel
mikestead.dotenv
ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
ms-vscode.sublime-keybindings
ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin
ms-vscode.wordcount
msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome
nitayneeman.puppeteer-snippets
octref.vetur
patbenatar.advanced-new-file
pflannery.vscode-versionlens
PKief.material-icon-theme
plibither8.remove-comments
pnp.polacode
Prisma.vscode-graphql
redhat.java
RobbOwen.synthwave-vscode
RoscoP.ActiveFileInStatusBar
samrapdev.outrun
sdras.night-owl
Shan.code-settings-sync
silvenon.mdx
sodatea.velocity
sveggiani.vscode-field-lights
teabyii.ayu
tinkertrain.theme-panda
vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag
VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode
vitaliymaz.vscode-svg-previewer
vscjava.vscode-java-debug
vscjava.vscode-java-dependency
vscjava.vscode-java-pack
vscjava.vscode-java-test
vscjava.vscode-maven
WakaTime.vscode-wakatime
wesbos.theme-cobalt2
whizkydee.material-palenight-theme
will-stone.plastic
wuz.dank-neon
xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets
yummygum.city-lights-theme
zhuangtongfa.Material-theme
Zignd.html-css-class-completion
```

Note: I'm on Windows but would love bindings for Mac as well since I'll switch back to Mac in a week.

Comment: It isn't completely clear to me what you are trying to accomplish, but see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067138/select-multiple-lines-with-cursors-at-each-line-start/49072073#49072073 Select your text first, Ctrl+A for all of it, Shift+Alt+I to pur a cursor at the end of all selected lines, and lastly Function+Home to move those cursors to the beginning of the lines - if you have wrapped lines - hit Function+Home again.

Comment: I just want cursors to be at the start of each line. You are perfectly understanding my problem. And that's what I did. But instead of `Function+Home`, I used `Ctrl+Home` but what happens is multiple cursors are removed & only a single cursor remains at the start of the line. So I did everything you suggested but the last part `Ctrl+Home` removes multiple cursors & makes it a single cursor at the start of the line.

Comment: So I checked the linked question and as the 2nd answer suggests `Shift+Home` does the job, not `Ctrl+Home` :)

Comment: Your question didn't say you wanted the lines selected.  So Function-Home to go to beginning of lines without selecting, shift+home to select (on Windows).

Comment: yeah i didn't wanted it to be selected but its the only way its working. Besides my keyboard doesn't have a `Fn` key

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49901397/6141587). Copy pasting the linked answer below.

**On Windows:**

1. Select the lines.
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> (will add multiple cursors)
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Home</kbd> (will go at the beginning of each line and be selected)

**On Mac :**

1. Select the lines.
2. <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> (will add multiple cursors)
3. <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd>
   (will go at the beginning of each line and be selected)