# How to set all columns not null while creating table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to create table which should have not null constraint for all of columns.

Is there any way to set all of columns not null instead of placing it in front of each column's name?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to set all of columns not null instead of placing it in front of each column's name?

No, sorry to say.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, there is a way to make it fast. You can type in many lines in the same type by using `ALT + mouse` or `ALT + SHIFT + ARROWS`. It's works nearly in every editor. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037808/multiline-editing-in-vscode) for more details. It's a very useful trick when you need to edit/add a lot of same words in consecutive lines i.e. `NOT NULL` as in your case.