# Visual Studio Code: How to remove html tags and write to multiple lines at the same time?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

How does one do this:

[image: This what I want to achieve]

I found many useful tricks here  [Multiline editing in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037808/multiline-editing-in-vscode)

I know I could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd>
I know I could just press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> to and delete the opening li tags together. But the closing li tags are not in the same line of sight.

How does one do what is being shown in the above example.

Comment: select the common text and then use `CTRL + D` to select matching text I believe

Comment: @NickParsons You need to press CTRL + D several times to select all matching elements. If there are 15 </li> tags you will have to press it 15 times.

Comment: Ah yeah, I should have mentioned that, my bad. But does that do what you were after?

Comment: Once you have the multiple cursors the cursor movement keys apply the action to every cursor, so if you have all the opening tags selected, just press End to jump to end of line.

Comment: @Strelok oh sweet. I think combining your comment with Nick's is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, combining valuable comments by @Nick and @Strelok (thanks guys), Here is the answer:

**Step 1:** Select `<li>` using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>

**Step 2:** Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> several times till all the `<li>` tags are selected.

**Step 3:** Press <kbd>Del</kbd>

**Step 4:** Press <kbd>End</kbd>

**Step 5:** Press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete closing `</li>` tags

**Step 6:** Press <kbd>Home</kbd>

**Step 7:** Press <kbd>Left</kbd> key till you are at the right spot inside `<a>` tag. And then type whatever you wish to.

Even though I could deduce this answer only from the comments by @Nick and @Strelok, I decided to post the answer myself because it would be unfair to mark one as answer when both the comments were equally helpful. I am going to keep the question open for now just in case someone comes up with a better way. Perhaps a way to avoid pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> multiple times.

Comment: Ctrl+D is what being used in the GIF, but I'd use 'Add cursor below' hotkey instead (I think it's Ctrl+Alt+Down by default). This way you don't need to select `<li>` first.

Answer (score 2):

There is an emmet command that will remove a tag for you: `editor.emmet.action.removeTag`.  It is currently unbound to any keybinding but you could easily make your own.  Here is a demo without binding that command:

1. Select your `<li>`'s however you choose [I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> in the demo - but that selects all of them in the file which may or may not be appropriate for your use case.]
2. Trigger the `editor.emmet.action.removeTag`
3. Arrow over to your insertion points.

Pretty easy especially if you give that emmet command a keybinding.

[image: emmet remove tag description]

Answer (score 1):

You have the entire keyboard shortcut overview directly in VSC <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or Help menu 'Keyboard Shortcuts Reference'

1. Mark your desired characters.
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to mark all similar occurrences.
3. Change everything simultaneously.
4. Repeat for additional changes.