# How to get multiple cursors in VS Code at beginning or end of lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In Atom, you are able to select multiple lines then hit `Command + Shift + L` followed by the left arrow key or the right arrow key to put multiple cursors at the beginning or end of each selected line.

When trying to do the same command in VS Code it doesn't work? How can I achieve the same behavior in VS Code?

[image: Atom Multicursor Lines]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiline editing in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037808/multiline-editing-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Shift+Alt+I` will put cursors on each line end.

For the beginnings, I guess you can just `Ctrl+Alt+Down` at the beginning to add more cursors.

Comment: Just hit `Home` after the `Shift+Alt+I`.  You could also look at `Column Selection Mode` or `Ctrl+Alt+Downarrow` (Add cursor below) after putting the cursor on the top line where you want it is probably the easiest.

Comment: Press CTRL + A to select all of the text
Press SHIFT + ALT + I to insert multiple cursors at the end of each line
Press Home twice to jump to the start of every line

Comment: It's `Option+Shift+I` on macOS.

Comment: `Option+Shift+I` works if you select all the lines first.