# JSONB to table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm new and still learning.

I have a table in jsonB format:

[image: jsonb input]

And I need to output be like:

[image: Output]

Is there a easy way to do this. The jsonb has around 100 key. So it would be  converted to 100 columns.

Is there a way to do this dynamically. I mean, if the number of columns or column name change, it´s not necessary to update the query.

Comment: Would be way easier to do client-side.

Comment: Do you have a table with the same columns? That would make it easy.

Comment: Does [this](https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2018/06/19/crosstab-pivot.html) answer your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,

For each key you need to create a column. To get all keys listed you can use this command:

```
select 
    jsonb_object_keys(u) 
from YOURTABLE;
```

After get the list of keys, I suggest you to use a text editor, to make easier the process. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037808/multiline-editing-in-visual-studio-code) certainly will help you.

After created your template you will need to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   u->'prb0' as prb0,
   u->'prb1' as prb1,
   u->'prb1' as prb2,
   ....
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

I strongly recommend you to create an intermediate table to store this query, and make it easier for furthers queries.

Comment: Henriqe Ferreira - Thanks alot. It worked. I created the query with all the 100 keys as you mentioned

Comment: I'm glad I helped :)