# VsCode multiple cursor on same variable

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

VsCode has a command (`ctrl+alt+l` as shown [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor)) to select all occurrences of the word in a file. It's also possible for the [rename symbol](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_rename-symbol). But **is there a way to select only occurrences of the same variable** ?

In this example would like to be able to select in the same time the word `value` of the first and third line but not the one of the second line.

```py
def square(value):
    '''Return the square of provided value.'''
    return value * value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `F2` and rename the variable. It will rename only, but all the variable instances in the file. When the cursor is on the variable you want to rename, click `F2` you will see a prompt like this.

[image: rename variable in VSCode]

Comment: Thank you. That's why I was asking for something similar for multi-cursor selection. But perhaps it's not possible.

Comment: There's this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45277437/400836 , CMD+F, then option+enter to highlight all to edit;

Also saw an even shorter way, CTRL+F2 (or in mac) CMD+F2, will. highlight the word all + cursor.