# How can I edit a few selected lines simultaneously in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, edit, shortcut

Only finding the ctrl + alt + arrows to edit multiple lines that are glued to each other. I want to select few random lines and write the same code in them simultaneously. How can I do it??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiline editing in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037808/multiline-editing-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: or use `Ctrl+D` to select a similar string forward

Answer (score 0):

You can simply click the desired line or location whilst holding down the `alt` key.