# How to place a cursor after every N characters in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Say for example I have a very long line of text in a single line in VS Code (let's pretend that the example given below is very long).

```sh
0xffffffffeeeeeeee02020202aaaaaaaa
```

At first I placed my cursor after the characters **`0x`**.
(the **cursor** is denoted by the **`|`** character in the example below)

```sh
0x|ffffffffeeeeeeee02020202aaaaaaaa
```

Then I want to add more cursors after every **N** characters from the current cursor. In this case **N** is equal to **8** and I want to do this twice to add two more cursor like in the example below.

```sh
0x|ffffffff|eeeeeeee|02020202aaaaaaaa
```

So that after I press the following sequence of keys in the keyboard, in this case those sequence of keys are **`,(space)0x`** I should be able to get these final result.

```sh
0x, 0x|ffffffff, 0x|eeeeeeee, 0x|02020202aaaaaaaa
```

After I deselect the cursors I should be getting this

```
0x, 0xffffffff, 0xeeeeeeee, 0x02020202aaaaaaaa
```

Is this possible to do in VS code?

Comment: This is called multiedit. Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037808/multiline-editing-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#select-by-multi-cursor-with-keyboard)

It has a command to add a new cursor by keyboard

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i ctrl+alt+right", // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "selectby.addNewSelection",
    "args": {"offset": 8}
  }
```

Now the offset is hard coded but I will add an option to ask the user the offset.

The possibility of the context switch is already working. I have to update the README.

Answer (score 2):

There is a straightforward regex that can do what you want:

Find: `^0x|(.{8})(?!$)`

But you have to enable the `Find in Selection` option and trigger the `Select All Matches` command yourself after entering it.

Or use a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) and this keybinding to automate it:

```
{
  "key": "alt+p",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
          "sequence": [
        {
          "command": "editor.actions.findWithArgs",
          "args": {
            "findInSelection": true,
            "isRegex": true,
            "searchString": "^0x|.{8}",
          }
        },
        "editor.action.selectAllMatches",
        "cursorRight"
      ]
  },
}
```

You must select up to where you want the last cursor and then trigger the macro.

- Because of a flaky implementation, you **must** start with the `Find in Selection` option disabled in the Find Widget.  I haven't found a way around that.
- The setting `Editor > Find: Seed Search String From Selection` must be set to `never`.  Otherwise your selected text will over-ride the `searchString` from the macro above.

[image: put a cursor every eight characters macro]

---

---

Here is the pure regex method with no extensions:

1. Enter `^0x|(.{8})(?!$)` in your Find Widget with the regex option enabled.

`^0x` the first part of the string you ultimately want a cursor after.

`(.{8})(?!$)` select each 8-character block, but not the last - that is why there is a negative lookahead for the end of the line `(?!$)` - so the last 8 characters are not matched. Don't worry, there will be a cursor in front of those last 8 characters as you want.  `(.{8})` doesn't actually need to be in a capture group, it is just clearer to see.

2. Select **all** the text to match: `0xffffffffeeeeeeee`.  Stop the selection there - wherever you want the last cursor.
3. Enable the `Find in Selection` option in the Find Widget by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to select all the find matches respecting the `Find in Selection` option: `editor.action.selectHighlights`.

Step (4) will select your matches - you should have 4 for the above string.  But you don't want the matches selected you just want a cursor at the beginning of each, so do step (5):

5. Right arrow: this cancels each selection with a cursor at the right end of each.
6. Type.

[image: every eight characters regex]

Comment: I tried `(.{8})` regex search and `Ctrl+D` but was unable to get it working

Comment: @rioV8 I have posted the pure regex version.  5 straightforward steps but good for a macro.

Comment: I see I made it for the entire line and for some reason the OP didn't want the last 8 characters separated...

Comment: Fixed for partial selection.

Comment: you don't have to switch focus to the editor in step 4, focus in the Find dialog, press `Alt+L` and you select all and move focus to editor. I think they have changed the finding of regex, I think I was able to enter a regex, focus to editor, press `F3` and then `Ctrl+D` for each next occurrence of the regex.

Comment: It looks like you are right - for some reason there is a big difference between using the mouse to select the `Find in Selection` option and `Alt+L` ??  I was using the mouse and then `Alt+Enter` **de-selects** the selection option and you get everything in the file - I consider that a bad bug.  I'll revise to simplify.  Thanks.