# Cursor on multiple lines in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often use Alt + Shift + arrow to have the cursor on multiple lines in SSMS and e.g. ISE for PowerShell. But when I do this in Visual Studio Code or Azure Data Studio the functionality is different and the line gets duplicated.

How can I have this multiple cursors in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: It's `Alt+Ctrl+Arrow` by default in vscode.  You could remap that if you wanted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiline editing in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037808/multiline-editing-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following ways are available:

- Click on a place with <kbd>Alt</kbd> pressed to add a cursor there.
- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> to place a cursor in the same spot in the previous/next line.
- Select multiple areas at once by dragging while pressing with the middle button (pressing down the scrolling wheel)

In most other IDEs the same shortcuts are available with Ctrl/Cmd instead of Alt. You can change it by adding `"editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd"` to your settings.

The shortcut you are attempting is actually used for line manupulation, also very handy:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> to move the current line up or down. This is very useful for sorting lines.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> will copy the current line up or down, and move your cursor with it. Also very useful when combined with comment toggle, in case you want to comment a line and modify a copy of it.

As a general advice, you can open the command palette and just type what you are trying to do, it will show the shortcut at its right. For instance, opening it (with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and typing `shortcut reference` will offer you the option to open the list of all available shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Alt + Click where you want the cursor

Answer (score 1):

Both of the below will work, which one I use depends on the use case.

Alt + Click

Ctrl + Alt + Arrow

[Additionally a helpful list of default hotkeys for vsc](https://images.app.goo.gl/YJHMGpUwdYggA7Ay6)