# VSCode multicursor Lubuntu

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, multicursorediting

Does anyone know to make multicursor work in vscode in Lubuntu 18.04? I already search everywhere and I didn't find anything. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: As in https://stackoverflow.com/q/29953479/6309?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the atom keymap extension and just use Shift+Ctrl with up/down arrow keys for multi-cursor.

Answer (score 0):

just click on the "**Selection**" menu then click on "**Switch to Ctrl+click**" for Multi-cursor".
[image: Snap]

It's because Ubuntu uses alt+click for moving windows
So 
instead, you can change this behaviour in setting->shortcuts.