# VS Code: refactor comma delimited variable declarations to one variable per line

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, refactoring

Using an atomic procedure from Visual Studio Code or an extension (not multi-line cursor)

```
const db          = require('./lib/db'),
    path        = require('path'),
    fs          = require('fs'),
    Logger      = require('./lib/log.lib'),
    rfs         = require('rotating-file-stream'),
    morgan      = require('morgan'),
    mung        = require('express-mung'),
    compression = require('compression'),
    bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
```

into this

```
const db          = require('./lib/db');
const path        = require('path');
const fs          = require('fs');
const Logger      = require('./lib/log.lib');
const rfs         = require('rotating-file-stream');
const morgan      = require('morgan');
const mung        = require('express-mung');
const compression = require('compression');
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
```

?

Comment: Press `Alt` and click. You'll get multi-line cursor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple cursors in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953479/multiple-cursors-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a find and replace with a regex.

Find: `^(const)*\s*(.*)[,;]$`

Replace: `const $2;`

Select your text, click the `Find in Selection` option and replace all.

[image: demo of regex replace working]

---

Or put it into a snippet:

```
 {
    "key": "alt+4",           // whatever keybinding you wish
    "command":  "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/\\s*(const)*\\s*(.*)[,;]/\tconst $2;\n/g}"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
  },
```

Select your text and trigger the snippet.  you may have to indent them all some but they will be aligned.