# How do I insert the cursor exactly into the mouse position?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want exactly the same behavior as VisualStudio's Alt+Click and Drag selecting

But, vscode's Alt+Shift+Click or MiddleButton Click is different working.

**vscode's behavior does not insert taps/spaces to the clicked position!**

please help me T.T

I already know the following:

[Multiple cursors in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953479/multiple-cursors-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just assume you're talking about Virtual Space.

It's not implemented in vscode.

Open Issue: [#13960](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13960)

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted.