# Multiple cursors in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reason I cannot use multiple cursors in VS Code, does anybody know which settings allows for multiple selections of rows at a time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you create multiple cursors in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953479/how-can-you-create-multiple-cursors-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you find this answer:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics

Basically you press **alt + click** on desired places