# VSCode multicursor next occurrence undo

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, is it possible to undo a multicursor selection if you have selected one too many while using Ctrl+D?

Comment: try the key combo `Ctrl+U`

Comment: why not just use the multi-cursor-modifier and click the cursor you want to remove? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453729/11107541

Comment: There is a command that would work in your case: `Move Last Selection To Previous Find Match` but in your exmple I don't see any advantage over `Ctrl+U`.

Comment: Thank you @rioV8 and @Mark, `Ctrl-U` did the trick.