# Changing Multicursormodifier makes follow link not working in RedHat linux, can follow link modifier be changed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using RedHat Linux for a project and have issues getting both multicursor modifier and "follow link"-clicking working in VSCode at the same time.

So

- with default alt as multicursor modifier, then ctrl click on links works, but not adding multicursor with alt click.
- with ctrl as multi cursor modifier, then adding multicursor works, but neither ctrl or alt clicking on links works.

Can the "follow link" click modifier be changed in some way in vscode?

Alt + click is bound to move window in RedHat/Mate. I can change it to "Super" key, but it will not help.

I found a similar question in here, but the solutions doesn't work for me:

- [How can you create multiple cursors in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953479/how-can-you-create-multiple-cursors-in-visual-studio-code)